# Associations 'has_many' and 'has_one' with same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I have a Fabric model that has_many Prices.

```
    Class Fabric < ActiveRecord::Base  
        has_many :prices, :as => :priceable, :dependent => :destroy
    end

    class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :amount,
                :quoted_date,
                :valid_till

        belongs_to :priceable, :polymorphic => true
    end
```

How can I add an association to give latest_price?

I need to add a price range search condition in ransack search form for Fabrics which should return all Fabrics with latest_price_amount in the given range, where LatestPrice is the Price with most recent quoted_date.

```
    <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :latest_price_amount_gteq %>
        <%= f.text_field :latest_price_amount_lteq %>
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
```

I have studied [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648792/what-is-the-rails-way-to-enforce-a-has-many-but-has-only-one-current-associati), and the first approach seems fine to me, but can I replace `has_one` with `belongs_to`, because a Fabric may or may not have a Price? If not, can you suggest a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193922/scope-on-each-last-elements-of-a-has-many-relation) help you.